# lscpu lists cpu clock speed incorrectly

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

I have a laptop that runs Ubuntu 13.04, with Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz, which gets reported correctly with `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. However, the clock speeds are listed as `800 MHz`:

`lscpu`:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              4589.60
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K 
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Is this a problem? Specifically, can ubuntu fully utilize the cpu?

Comment: This may be what your CPU is currently running at, the Intel SpeedStep feature or similar changes the clock speed to save power/reduce heat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the current speed. The result should be the same as by using the command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

The command `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor` will indicate the power scheme for the CPU.

Use the followings 2 commands to view the max and min frequency (allowed).

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq
```

Comment: `cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq` doesn't exist in my computer (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: There are some explanation on it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/218586/682592). `intel_pstate` CPU freq driver doesn't provide this.